# How to serialize a Zend_Mail_Message?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

I have several `Zend_Mail_Message` objects that I got from an IMAP query.
Now I want to serialize each message individually.

However, it seems that a simple:

```
serialize($message);
```

doesn't work because the message has attachments (multipart), and the parts don't get serialized.

So, how to serialize a complete `Zend_Mail_Message` object, including parts (attachements)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically Zend_Mail_Message has cache mechanism, so when you get a part from the message it doesn't ask the IMAP server again for that part.

So the key was to warm up the cache before serializing:

```
$i=0;
while ($part = $message->getPart($i) {
  $i++;
}

$serialization=serialize($message); //now it saves the whole message.
```